# Check if read input is available in var

Tags: bash, server

I try to list all Folders in `/etc/nginx/html/`.

I use this code:

```
folders=`for i in $(ls -d */ | grep -Ev "(backups)"); do echo ${i%%/}; done`
```

Now I get all folders with names non containing "backups".

Now I want to count the folder and save it into var. I use this code:

```
folders_count=( $folders )
echo ${#folders_count[@]}
```

It works. I get a list of all folders and I can count the folders.

Now I try to write a script that reads user input (or better, offers 1,2,3 choices, but I do not know how to do it) and install a script like Prestashop (as an example) into the folder the user has chosen if there are more than 1 folder.

Here is my code:

```
folders_count=( $folders )
echo ${#folders_count[@]}
echo
if [ ${#folders_count[@]} -gt 1 ]; then
  echo "${info} Please choose a Website for Prestashop:" | awk '{ print strftime("[%H:%M:%S] |"), $0 }'
  # for websites in $folders; do
  # echo "${info} $folders" | awk '{ print strftime("[%H:%M:%S] |"), $0 }'
  # echo "${info} $folders" | awk '{ print strftime("[%H:%M:%S] |"), $0 }'
  # done
  echo "$folders" | awk '{ print strftime("[%H:%M:%S] |"), $0 }'
  #read websites_for_prestashop
  read -e -i "$websites_for_prestashop" -p "Please enter your Website: " input
  websites_for_prestashop="${input:-$websites_for_prestashop}"
  if [ "$websites_for_prestashop" == "$folders" ]; then
    echo "Website is $websites_for_prestashop"
  else
    echo "Website $websites_for_prestashop is not found"
  fi
  #echo "${info} Please choose a Website for Prestashop:" | awk '{ print strftime("[%H:%M:%S] |"), $0 }'
else
  echo "nix"
fi
```

I dont know how I can make it work :/

Can anyone help me to fix it?

I would like to list the available folders. Then the user should be able to select in which folder he would like to install the script.

Folders:

```
[0] Folder 1
[1] Folder 2
[2] Folder 3
[3] Folder 4
....
```

Then a query will appear:
Please select an order for the installation:

The selection of the folder should then be stored in the variable read `websites_for_prestashop`

Comment: Have you looked at the `select` command which can create a menu from an array very easily, see: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/115 and http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_06.html

Comment: this if what im looking for! Thank you!

Comment: mh in dont know how i can breat out the loop :o
  select websites_for_prestashop in $folders;
  do
    echo "You picked $websites_for_prestashop."
  done

Comment: sorry....break....thank oyu Solved!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what your script is supposed to be doing.  There are a bunch of lines commented out, the only assignment for `websites_for_prestashop` contains a reference to the variable itself and occurs after this variable is first used, and the script ultimately does nothing.

What I can tell you is that the way you extract filenames is not the right way to do it.  Parsing the output of `ls` is not a good idea (see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and the way you do it will fail on any file with a name containing spaces, among other things.

This would be one way to do it:

```
declare -a folders=()
for f in */
do
  [[ $f =~ backups ]] || folders+=("${f%/}")
done
echo "Folder count is: ${#folders[@]}"
```

Comment: I would like to list the available folders. Then the user should be able to select in which folder he would like to install the script.

Folders:
`
[0] Folder 1
[1] Folder 2
[2] Folder 3
[3] Folder 4
As shown in Fig

Then a query will appear:
Please select an order for the installation:

The selection of the folder should then be stored in the variable read `websites_for_prestashop`

i updated first Post

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help@
https://stackoverflow.com/users/2416376/olli-k

https://stackoverflow.com/users/7422249/fred

Solution is easy:

```
folders=`for i in $(ls -d */ | grep -Ev "(backups)"); do echo ${i%%/}; done`

        echo "${info} Please choose a Website for Prestashop:" | awk '{ print strftime("[%H:%M:%S] |"), $0 }'
        select websites_for_prestashop in $folders;
        do
             echo "You picked $websites_for_prestashop."
             break
        done
```